# How to install Symfony2-plugin into Aptana

Tags: symfony, plugins, aptana, aptana3

I am using Aptana 3.4.2 and want to get Symfony2-plugin into Aptana. But if I try to install the plugin it says that org.eclipse.emf.ecore.feature.group is missing. So if I try to install this package (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates/) it will say that something else is missing.
So I need to install this Symfony2-plugin. How can I get it into Aptana?

Answer (score 1):

There [doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311902/do-the-aptana-developers-plan-to-support-the-symfony2?rq=1) seem to be any official support for Symfony 2 on Aptana, however [this](https://github.com/pulse00/Symfony-2-Eclipse-Plugin/issues/121) might be of help;  you can use the aptana plugin on top of eclipse; however that also has a couple of incompatibilities. Probably worth considering an IDE such as NetBeans or PHPStorm, or using Aptana solely as an editor.